# Is it possible to load an image from bitmap and overlay a chart over it using windows form chart control?

Tags: .net, windows, bitmap, overlay

I want to use .NET windows form chart control. In their examples, there is not any example in which there is a bitmap and some chart overlayed.

Is it possible, and if so, does anyone got any idea how to do it?

Comment: Odds are there is some `BackgroundImage` property that will do just that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
...

//IMPORTANT: For this event to work the event handler must be added to the InitializeComponent()
//  method. We recommend that you add the event using the Properties window in the IDE  
private void chart1_PostPaint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Painting series object
    if(sender is System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series)
    {
        // Add custom painting only to the series with the name "Series2"
        Series    series = (Series)sender;
        if(series.Name == "Series2")
        {
            // Find data point with maximum Y value
            DataPoint    dataPoint = series.Points.FindMaxValue();

            // Load bitmap from file 
            System.Drawing.Image bitmap = Bitmap.FromFile(this.Page.MapPath("MaxValueMarker.bmp"));

            // Set Red color as transparent
            ImageAttributes attrib = new ImageAttributes();
            attrib.SetColorKey(Color.Red, Color.Red, ColorAdjustType.Default);

            // Calculates marker position depending on the data point X and Y values
            RectangleF    imagePosition = RectangleF.Empty;
            imagePosition.X = (float)e.ChartGraphics.GetPositionFromAxis(
                "Default", AxisName.X, dataPoint.XValue);
            imagePosition.Y = (float)e.ChartGraphics.GetPositionFromAxis(
                "Default", AxisName.Y, dataPoint.YValues[0]);
            imagePosition = e.ChartGraphics.GetAbsoluteRectangle(imagePosition);
            imagePosition.Width = bitmap.Width;
            imagePosition.Height = bitmap.Height;
            imagePosition.Y -= 10;
            imagePosition.X -= 1;

            // Draw image
            e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 
                Rectangle.Round(imagePosition),
                0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height,
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel, 
                attrib);

            // Dispose image object
            bitmap.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```